# Voiceover with tabindex=0

Tags: accessibility, voiceover, section508

Working on web-accessibility with VoiceOver. I have a table with `tabindex=0` for each row. VoiceOver doesn't read the content of the rows with `tabindex` and it reads fine without it

I had to use tabindex because clicking on the row shows more information about the row and tabindex provides the ability to view more information for users with only keyboard

Comment: Do you have a URL? Is the extra information visually hidden in a scrolling region or is only shown on focus?

Comment: Only shown on focus

Comment: I just tried a simple table with tabindex=0 on one of the rows and Voiceover on iOS works fine.  Using swipe left/right, I can get to the row and each cell is read as I swipe.  On OSX, it also worked.  I could tab to the row and the entire row was read, or I can use quick nav and go to each cell element and they're read.

Comment: It sounds almost like you have a tool-tip-style feature. It sounds like the feature is not working. With some sample code or a URL we could debug it. If you are showing it via CSS `:focus` it should just work. If you are using JS then seeing the code is necessary.